# Flutter ScrollController in ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-animation

I made a chat app in flutter . i want when i open the chat page automatic scroll to the last message like real whats app or messenger . i want when i open the page i be in the last message . i dont want to use reverse in list View

i tried to do this in innit state but it didn't work when i open the chat page for first time but after that it work fines

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          scrollController.jumpTo(scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jumpTo` will instancly move to bottom after 1st frame is build. You can include a `FutureDelay(..)` but `.animateTo` looks better.

```dart
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await scrollController.animateTo(
          scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
          curve: Curves.bounceIn);
    });
  }
```

Find more about [/ScrollController/animateTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/animateTo.html)

Comment: not working when i open the chat page for the first time too

Comment: are you using  tabBarView as parent?  or other widget that isnt lazy loading

Comment: depends on parent widget you are using

Comment: thank u it works when i use future delay